# vscode's testing interface does not work properly with django

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pytest, python-unittest

`unittest` does **not** create a test database and runs on the production database.

```
`"python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,`
```

`pytest` creates a test database but **fails** with `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateDatabase`, if the database was not manually deleted.

```
`"python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,`
```

Both also don't seem to run django `manage.py` command since:

1. the test runner does not execute `TEST_RUNNER = 'test.test.test'`.
2. the overridden test `Command` class does not run either.

```
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "./app1/tests.py",
    "./app2/tests.py",
  ],
```

```
  "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    ".",
    "-p",
    "tests.py"
  ],
```

Note that the following launch command in `launch.json` works 100% properly (test runner and command execute) and all tests run and pass correctly but I would like to use the vscode testing interface.

```
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "-v"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": false,
        },
```